# Java Conversion of String to decimal ( ASCII )?

Tags: java, string, int, byte, decimal

```
String buffer = "c";
```

Conversion by Decimal.
I wanna change buffer value to decimal value.

```
In ASCII Table
DEC     HEX     CHAR
 99      63      c
```

So, Finally 
    `buffer -> 99 ( return value int or String and something )`

How Can I Change that value?

```
Integer.parseInt(buffer, 12) -> returns 12
```

But I wanna get `99`

is it Possible to conversion?

Comment: It already is 99. No conversion necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String buffer = "c";
char ch = buffer.charAt(0);
System.out.println((int)ch);
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
System.out.println((int)ch);
```

where ch is a char

Of course in you code you have a string, so maybe you need to get the first char or something

Answer (score 0):

```
String buffer = "abc";
for(int i=0;i<buffer.length();i++)
{
    System.out.println((int)buffer.charAt(i));
}
```